# Do planes have "chassis"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In my native language the word that sounds a lot like "chassis" means wheels that come out from the plane when it's about to land.

I know for sure that in English it means the base frame of a car. But does it also mean wheels of the plane in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, "*chassis*" is not used for the wheels of an airplane, nor of any other vehicle. Nor can I think of any similar-sounding word that is so used.

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chassis) gives as the definition:

> the supporting frame of a structure (such as an automobile or television)

The wheels of an airplane, and the structure that supports them are called the "*carriage*" or  "*undercarriage*", but more often the term "*landing gear*" is used.